# React-Native Build Issues Android for Mac

Tags: android, sdk, react-native

I'm getting the following terminal error after running `react-native run-android`

Error message: `failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /usr/local/opt/android-sdk`

Here are the packages I've installed with android manager [image]

Here is also the code from my build.gradle file containing the versioning etc - I have a feeling this has to do with the versions set.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The android build tools are separate from the platform SDK. You're probably missing the SDK Platform install for Android API level 23. Scroll down and install it.

Comment: Haha yep found this was the case as soon as I posted. Thanks!